# Global object that has different functionality for each page?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am in the process of developing some js that will have functions that will be called from server side code as well as other client side js. I have some pretty generic functions such as functions that get a list of objects with a dynamic property.

If I had `PageA` and `PageB` as my main pages global javascript object and `GlobalComm` as my class that will handle communication coming from both server and client, what would be a way for me to structure `GlobalComm` so that given function `GetListWithProp` function could run custom code for `PageA` and then turn around and run completely different code for `PageB`?

Currently I was thinking of having something like this:

```
var GlobalClass = function() { //code };
GlobalClass.prototype.GetListWithProp = function() { //generic code };

GlobalComm = new GlobalClass();
```

And then in `PageA` I would override `GlobalClass.prototype.GetListWithProp`.

Comment: Did you debbuged it at the console to see how it is called, parameters, other globals that may affect it and etc...?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Nothing is broken. I'm just trying to figure out what is a standard architecture for this problem.